# How to make column editable false based on some condition in Mui Data Grid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

I want to make editing false for score column if there is user enter data in percentage column and vice versa with score column.
I followed below example from official MUI Grid example.
[example followed](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/editing/#full-featured-crud)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxblT.png)

I am not able to find any similar example in the docs.